# converting time to digestible JSON string with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, httparty

The following string returns results

```
@result = HTTParty.post(
  'https://test.co.uk/search', 
  :body => '{ "requestAuditInfo": {  "agentCode": "MLG001",  
  "requestDateTime": "2018-07-29T07:03:38Z" [...]
```

whereas

```
@result = HTTParty.post(
  'https://test.co.uk/search', 
  :body => '{ "requestAuditInfo": {  "agentCode": "MLG001",  
  "requestDateTime": Time.now.utc.iso8601 [...]
```

returns nil

Console for `Time.now.utc.iso8601` returns  `"2018-07-29T07:03:38Z"` which is the desired string for the successful call.

What am I getting wrong?

**update**

```
:body => "{ 'requestAuditInfo': {  'agentCode': 'MLG001',
  'requestDateTime': '2018-07-29T07:03:38Z'
```

is NOT being digested by the receiving API, returning NIL results

Comment: no, as I was attempting to use the iso8601 pre-set format

Comment: interpolation is missing in your quotes. Ruby code needs to be interpolated with `#{}` when used in string. Replace with `#{Time.now.utc.iso8601}` and use double quotation - `"{ 'requestAuditInfo': {  'agentCode': 'MLG001',  
  'requestDateTime': #{Time.now.utc.iso8601} [...]` or use `%Q` as `:body => %Q|{ "requestAuditInfo": {  "agentCode": "MLG001", #{Time.now.utc.iso8601} [...]|`

Comment: the double quotation I had tried, but as the update shows, it is not arriving properly to server.  the `%Q| [...] | ` option runs with the string `"2018-07-29T07:03:38Z"` , but not the interpolation.

Comment: in CLI the quote handling is confirmed: `Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a string "requestDateTime": Time.now.utc.iso8601 [...]" as a parameter. If you want to pass ruby's `Time.now` as part of a string you need to interpolate it, like so:

`"requestDateTime": #{Time.now.utc.iso8601}"`